# How can I split this string of numbers with ranges?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string of numbers like this:

```
var string= "1,2,3,4-8,15,17,18-21,22";
```

How can I split it into an array that forms: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,15,17,18,19,20,21,22]`

UPDATE:Okay, code coming up in just a bit... trying to get a jsfiddle up.

```
var mystring= "1,2,3,4-8,15,17,18-21,22";

var array1= mystring.split(",");
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=array1;
var array2 = searchStringInArray ("-", array1);
document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML=array2;


function searchStringInArray (str, strArray) {
    for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
        if (strArray[j].match(str)) return j;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So around here I got stuck and was thinking there should be a better way. I know you have to search the array for hyphen split strings. But I failed to get them into another array that i could then insert into the first array.

https://jsfiddle.net/08au43ka/

Comment: Have you written any code yet?

Comment: What did you try? what did not work in your tests? post some code and explain the error, then people may chip in to help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var string= "1,2,3,4-8,15,17,18-21,22";
var arr=string.split(",");
var crr=[];
arr.forEach(function(a){
  brr= a.split("-");
  if(brr.length==2){
    var o=parseInt(brr[0]);
    var p=parseInt(brr[1]);
  for(var i=o;i<=p;i++)
    crr.push(i);
  }
  else
  crr.push(parseInt(brr[0]));
})
console.log(crr);
```

Comment: It's just your comment is exactly the same thing I wrote :) great solution

Comment: oh i should copy from your answer then

Comment: what does the condition if(brr.length==2) do?

Comment: @nilerafter24 if value contains `-` then length of split array would be 2 . else it would be 1.

Answer (score 2):

You could split first by comma, then by minus and reduce the whole to a new array with an inner loop for missing values.

```js
var string = "1,2,3,4-8,15,17,18-21,22",
    result = string.split(',').reduce(function (r, a) {
        var b = a.split('-').map(Number);
        do {
            r.push(b[0]);
            b[0]++;
        } while (b[0] <= b[1]);
        return r;
    }, []);
        
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i like the way you parsed into integer .

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace the ranges:

```js
var string = "1,2,3,4-8,15,17,18-21,22"

var regexRanges = /(\d+)-(\d+)/g;
var getRangeValues = function(range, start, end) {
    return Array(end - start + 1).fill(+start).map((x, i)=> x + i);
};

var result = JSON.parse('[' + string.replace(regexRanges, getRangeValues) + ']');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: why not use `JSON.parse`, to get a number array?

Comment: @NinaScholz. Nice idea!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
var string= "1,2,3,4-8,15,17,18-21,22";
var chunks = string.split(",");
var numbers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
  var chunk = chunks[i];
  if (chunk.indexOf('-') < 0) {
    numbers.push(parseInt(chunk));
  }
  else {
    var pair = chunk.split('-');
    for (var j = pair[0]; j <= pair[1]; j++) {
      numbers.push(parseInt(j));
    }
  }
}
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no known method for me to achieve what you want most likely you will need to write your own.

I'd split that string by commas, then i'd iterate through array looking for anything containing dash in it, if it contains dash grab that array item, parse it
get left side, get right side, create loop from `i = left` to `i<right`, push items into original array.